# ColdFusion Session Management / User Authentication with Multiple Domains

Tags: session, authentication, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have an issue where I need to perform authentication checks against users coming from a domain that resides on a separate server, database, and built using JSP.

Here is a quick overview of the process:

domain1.com (Users access this page to login to the site to get to the content they need. Uses J2EE Session IDs)

domain2.com (Content area where users can retrieve data built using ColdFusion 10. Data specific to each account is passed to the URL

e.g.,

```
domain2.com/content/content.cfm?customerID=12345

domain2.com/content/content.cfm?customerID=12345&pageid=AB12&type=CID1
```

The problem is that anyone could access domain2 without logging in through domain1.com just by entering in the URL. What are best security practices to authenticate sessions that are initially authenticated from a domain hosted on a completely different platform from my ColdFusion environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best Practise**: You have to use a shareable resource to authenticate between multiple environments properly, such as a database or a webservice that can be accessed by them. That's the only secure way.

**Security by Obscurity**: Encrypt the login information (e.g. customer's identity) on domain1.com and pass the encrypted token to domain2.com (on redirect). Make sure to use a padding with random content and an expiration timestamp in the encrypted token to prevent reuse of the token. domain2.com can easily decrypt the token and process the login from there on. The shareable resource in this case is the key used to encrypt/decrypt the token. AES is a good start.